# JQuery .mask doesn't allow more than 6 digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I'm trying to add dots to separate thounsands in html input tags of type number. It works only for numbers of 6 digits, after adding one more digit to the input, the number disapears.

Here is the code

**js**

```
$(document).on("change", 'input[type="number"]', function () {
    const inputSelectors = $('input[type="number"]')
    inputSelectors.mask("000.000.000.000.000.000", {reverse: true});
    
})
```

**html**

```
<input class="detail-input" name="detail-unit-price" type="number" step="any" value="0" required>
```

I've tried commenting every other javascript line to make sure that the problem is related only to this method and the problem persists. If I omit the .mask() method, everythong works perfectly.

Comment: If its type number, it will assume that a `.` is a decimal point, and two decimal points in a number is invalid.  I think you will have to use type text, and add a bunch of code to support checking if it’s  a valid number.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use attribute `type="number"` it will only accept numbers, such as `123.456`. The default number representation is to use the `.` dot for decimal separator, and `,` for magnitude indication. It looks like you want to reverse that, which is not supported by `type="number"`. That means, you can use that attribute.

Here is a solution that does not have the `type="number"` attribute, and adds the `.` for magnitude indication using regex instead of the `.mask()` jQuery plugin. Note that the `"change"` event only fires on focus loss, not on content change.

```js
$(document).on("change", '.detail-input', function () {
  let val = $(this).val();
  val = val
    .replace(/(\d)(\d{15})$/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d)(\d{12})$/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d)(\d{9})$/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d)(\d{6})$/, '$1.$2')
    .replace(/(\d)(\d{3})$/, '$1.$2');
  $(this).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="detail-input" name="detail-unit-price" value="0" required>
```